# Java reusing socket

Tags: java, sockets, http, stream

I have a socket connection over HTTP to a service. The service only supports HTTP/1.0 which by default closes the connection when a response is sent. There is a parameter added to this version of protocol - Connection: Keep-alive - to make it possible. The standard defines that the service should append this parameter to the header too. This is not happening the response header does not contain it.

When I get the inputStream from socket it does not support mark. So, can I safely assume that I will not be able to reuse the same connection to send/receive multiple requests/reponses?

**Update**
I have no control over the service and I build the request manually.

```
Socket socket = new Socket("server.com", 11111);

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

writer.write("POST HTTP/1.0\r\n");
writer.write("Host: " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostName() + "\r\n");
writer.write("Content-Length: " + length + "\r\n");
writer.write("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n");
writer.write("Connection: Keep-alive\r\n");
writer.write("\r\n");

writer.write(xmldata);
writer.flush();

List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(socket.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Do you use some library to build your http requests?

Comment: what you control? client or server or both? If you have no impact on server and it close connection there is nothing you can do, just create new socket..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP 1.0 standard ([RFC 1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt)) doesn't define any such thing actually. It's a post-added feature, and servers aren't obliged to support it.

Comment: @locke As EJP writes, you have to deal with servers not supporting this feature. But outside that, you should have caught the possibility that the socket is closed at any given time, anyway. Would you agree, EJP?

Comment: @Fildor Certainly. The server can close the connection any time, even in HTTP 1.1. And if it refuses to co-operate with `Connection: Keep-alive`, ditto.